# How do I get response object, print it and use it from Google after authenticating in next js 13 using next auth?

Tags: next.js, next-auth

```
import { useSession, signIn, signOut } from "next-auth/react";
const session =useSession();
const onClick = async () => {
    console.log('hello Iamhere')
     signIn("google");
    const response = session.response;
    console.log(`my response is ${response}`);
  };

 <button onClick={onClick}>Sign in</button>
```

I am able to sign in with google but not able to use its response object. All of these console logs are not printing anything.

This is how I am handling auth if that will come handy :

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

const handler = NextAuth({
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID?? '',
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET?? ''
    }),
  ],

})

export {handler as GET, handler as POST};
```

Please help me get the JSON object that contains tokens I get back from google. How will I see the tokens that google sends? I need to send a token to validate user at server side.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to enable `debug` mode in `route` during development such as below:

```
debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development",
```

The complete example of code

```
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID?? '',
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET?? ''
    }),
  ],
  debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development",
  ....
```

Thanks

Comment: How will this solve my problem? I don't think its related to my problem at all.

Comment: Try it and check the terminal log during the Oauth login.